# Configuring the output of getDate

Tags: thingsboard

There is a demo plugin that allows the devices to get the server's time. The current date and time is not very convenient for parsing in a microcontroller, and I would like to change the response to a Unix timestamp.

In the documentation it is stated that this is possible, but it not very clear how. Is there a guide on how can I configure the plug-in?

Also, getting the server's time is very important for non-ntp enabled devices (or when inside a VPN, without access to an NTP server). Are there any plans to integrate this functionality to the core of Thingsboard, or it will remain a demo plug-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you talk about is the part of the core now. You can edit plugin output format in the configuration of the plugin. Go to Plugins->your plugin->edit mode

Comment: Oh... I was checking the rule's settings instead of the plug-in's. I also didn't realised it was a core plugin, the "Demo" name confused me to thing it was, well... just a demo.

Comment: Looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html however, seems that there is no way to generate a UNIX timestamp. Correct?

Comment: Ah... I just found out that leaving the format string empty, returns a timestamp! It would be useful to document this I think!